# Do I need to sort a vector<int> if they were added to the vector in order?

Tags: c++, vector

Do I need to sort my vector if the items were read in from a file sequentially that was already sorted?  I don't want to incur the performance penalty if it's unnecessary.  For reference, this is what I'm using to build it, and each item is in order as it's being read in.

> Edited after @dribeas' comment

```
std::vector<int> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<int> elems;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while(std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(static_cast<int>(atoi(item.c_str())));
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Comment: Side note: if the reason for passing the vector in by reference is performance, forget it and return by value. It will make user code simpler and will be just as expensive besides making it clear that the function *creates* the vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to sort the vector. `push_back` adds elements *to the end* explicitly.

Note that your API is taking in `elems` and also returning it (by reference). What happens to any content the vector already contains?

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was my assumption, but thought it worth the ask.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking whether a `std::vector` will preserve the order in which you push items onto it, then yes. That is very much part of the contract.

Answer (score 3):

Provided the vector was *empty* when you started (that's not clear from your original sample code) and the items were added in the order you want, no, you do not need to sort, because [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) pushes items on to the *back* (end) of the vector:

> Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element.

---

Following your edit, the possibility of the list being non-empty to start with is now gone. This section still stands for the original question where that was a possibility.

If the vector wasn't empty to begin with, the stuff that was in there may be out of order even if you added the new stuff in order.

If you want to ensure it's sorted, but avoid sorting unless absolutely necessary, you can do that as a post-step after the addition, something like:

```
std::vector<int> &split (const std::string &s, char sep, std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    std::stringstream ss (s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline (ss, item, sep))
        vec.push_back (static_cast<int> (atoi (item.c_str ())));

    bool sorted = true;
    for (int i = vec.size() - 1; (i > 0) && sorted; i--)
        sorted = (vec[i] >= vec[i-1]);
    if (!sorted) {
        // Sort it here.
    }

    return vec;
}
```

This will be a relatively fast scan of the elements to ascertain whether or not they're sorted (and only until it finds the *first* out of order group).

If not sorted, it will sort them with your favourite sort algorithm (batteries not included), otherwise it will just return.

---

However, it may *still* be best to assume that the data may not arrive in the order you want. You can still use a similar method to only sort when necessary, with something like:

```
std::vector<int> split (const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<int> elems;
    std::stringstream ss (s);
    std::string item;
    int lastOne = std::numeric_limits<int>::min ();
    bool isSorted = true;

    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        int thisOne = atoi (item.c_str ());
        if (thisOne < lastOne) isSorted = false;
        elems.push_back (static_cast<int> (thisOne));
        lastOne = thisOne;
    }

    if (!isSorted) {
        // Sort it here.
    }

    return elems;
}
```

In that case, each element is checked against the last one to ensure it's at least as large. If not, the vector is flagged for sorting.

With that, there's a minimal cost in checking but it gives you the ability to handle data that doesn't follow the rules.

Comment: Note that C++11 has added a `std::is_sorted` algorithm.